# What is an Alias in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, reference, alias

I know how pointers work:

```
int a=10;
int* ptr=&a;
```

`cout<<ptr;` gives me the address of `a` stored in the `ptr`
`cout<<*ptr` gives me the value written on the address stored in `ptr`
'cout<<&ptr;' gives me the address of the `ptr` that I created.

So, what does an alias mean? Can someone explain it using an example, since I can't find any on the internet?

Comment: "*So, what does an alias mean?*" In what context? Where have you seen this word used with regard to C++?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the term **alias** to be a substitution for the *phrase* **"another name for"** . Following examples should clarify this:

```
using customint = int; //customint is "another name for" int
using customdouble = double; //customdouble is "another name for" double

int i = 0;
int &refI = i; //refI is "another name for" i
```

We generally don't use the term **alias** when talking about(in relation to) pointers.

In the above snippet, we can say that *customint is an alias for `int`*. We can also say this as *customint is another name for `int`*.

Similarly for others.

Answer (score 0):

"To alias" more or less means "to refer to". `*ptr` aliases `a`.

I haven't heard "alias" being used as a noun in relation to pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases and pointers address (forgive the pun) completely different issues (but see below). An **alias** allows you to define your own name for an existing, predefined *type* of variable. In C++ (since C++11), you can use the `using` keyword to define an alias:

```cpp
using MYINT = int;
```

After the above code, you can use the name `MYINT` (the *alias*) anywhere you would otherwise use an `int` declaration; thus, the following two lines would then be equivalent:

```cpp
int i;
MYINT i;
```

Before C++11 (and even in plain C), aliases are also available, using the `typedef` keyword:

```c
typedef int MYINT;
```

---

However, what *may* be confusing you is the use of the term "aliasing" (or "strict aliasing rules") when referring to pointers. These terms refer to the rules required when attempting to access one type of object through a pointer that is (formally) the address of a *different* type of object. This subject has been discussed in numerous posts on Stack Overflow; for example: [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/10871073)

Answer (score 0):

add & before declaration of reference. example : ref is an alias of a, in next example.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  int a (10);
  int& ref (a);
  std::cout << "\tref == " << ref << std::endl;
}
```